# Get runs from Experiment with specific Property in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I wish to get runs from my experience where I can filter from a specific item inside it.

From my `Experience` object, I get a generator containing all my `azureml.PipelineRun`

```
experiment.get_runs(type="azureml.PipelineRun")
```

In the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.experiment.experiment?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-experiment-experiment-get-runs) it is said we can add some type of filtering on the `properties` of the runs.

> Filter runs by "property" or {"property": "value"}

So I can filter on a one level property like this:

```
for run in experiment.get_runs(type="azureml.PipelineRun", properties={"azureml.git.branch": "my_branch"}):
     print(run)
```

> Run(Experiment: my_experiment,
> Id: my_id_1,
> Type: azureml.PipelineRun,
> Status: Running)

> Run(Experiment: my_experiment,
> Id: my_id_2,
> Type: azureml.PipelineRun,
> Status: Failed)

But how can I achieve this on the `azureml.parameters` property? `azureml.parameters` is a string representing a python dict.

Let say:

```
azureml.parameters <= {"a" : "abc", "b" : {"c" : "def", "e": "ghi"}}
```

How can I `get_runs` that matches only the sub key `c` with value `def` regardless of other keys/values ?

Answer (score 0):

we need to perform the nested dictionary to get the properties of the pipeline using Run.

Use the following code block to get the details of the pipleline.

```
for run in experiment.get_runs(type="azureml.PipelineRun", properties={"azureml.git.branch": "my_branch"}):
     print(run)
```

to get the below code block related set:

```
azureml.parameters <= {"a" : "abc", "b" : {"c" : "def", "e": "ghi"}}
```

Use the nested dictionary.

```
print(run[“b”][“c”])

Output: def
```

Comment: The issue with this, is that I will retrieve `runs` that I don't want with `experiment.get_runs`. It will get me a larger scope and then I have to handle each `azureml.parameters` one by one. So I'm retrieving "useless" data in my case. And since `experiment.get_runs` returns a generator, it can take quite a long time to find my "useful" run